# Why does the screen pop when the user clicks search button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Why does the screen pop when user searches the text from page.
I will explain the problem.
on click the button I go to next page. On next page there is search functionality implementation, but when user searches this text, it pop the screen and goes to previous one. I think my application is crashing.

These following text
1 ) **"(+?)"**

2)  q(?=u),
3 )  q(?!u)

3)   (?

Can you please tell me how to remove this crashing. Here is my code..

http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/4BAau/6/

```
    var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('('+searchTerm+')', "ig");
```

This does not work.

Comment: Those are reserved character for regex syntax so of course it breaks your search. You need to escape those.

Comment: But it is not search & ..?

Comment: Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4BAau/8/

Comment: Please check Matthias answer (I have edited it a bit too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An invalid `RegExp` pattern will throw an exception. Just [catch and resolve it](http://jsfiddle.net/4BAau/7/):

```
var searchTermRegEx, matches, selector = selector || "#realTimeContents";
try {
    searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('('+searchTerm+')', "ig");
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
```

If you want to support a query that uses reserved characters, escape them on your own since javascript [escape](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Guide/Functions#escape_and_unescape_functions%28Obsoleted_above_JavaScript_1.5%29) does it in the wrong way, e.g. `(` becomes `%28` instead of `\(`. You could do something like this beforehand:

```
searchTerm = searchTerm.replace(/([\(\)\.\+\?])/g, '\\$1');
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the line 4 of your js to this:

```
 var searchTermRegEx = new RegExp('('+escape(searchTerm)+')', "ig");
```

it will escape the text and the search will work correctly.